# Maximal order of a torsion element in a hyperbolic group

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose that $G = \langle X \rangle$ is a $\delta$-hyperbolic group, i.e. all geodesic triangles are $\delta$-thin (the inverse image of a point under the projections onto a tripod has diameter bounded by $\delta$).

It is a standard result that every finite subgroup of $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup contained in the ball of radius $2 \delta +1$ around the identity. It follows that every finite subgroup of $G$ is of size at most $|X|^{2\delta + 1} + 1$.

Can this result be improved if we only considered cyclic subgroups, i.e. can we get a better bound on the maximal order of a torsion element than $|X|^{2\delta + 1} + 1$?

EDIT:
Following the discussion in the comments, does the situation change if we assumed the group $G$ to be one-ended?

Comment: This bound looks suspicious: finite cyclic groups are hyperbolic, with $\delta(\langle a | a^n \rangle) = \lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor$, which is more than 1 + 1.

Comment: (nevermind, you consider symmetric generating sets)

Comment: In any case, if you consider $\Bbb Z/2^k$ with presentation $\langle x_1, \dots, x_{k-1} | x_i^2 = x_{i+1}, \dots, x_k^2 = 1\rangle$ or similar Cayley graph with low diameter, then exponent will be roughly exponential in triangle thinness.

Comment: @xsnl I was more thinking about infinite non-elementary case, but I think I see where you are going. Intuitively, a free product of a $\delta_1$-hyperbolic and $\delta_2$-hyperbolic group will be $\max\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$-hyperbolic, so taking a free product of a bunch of $\mathbb{Z}/{2^k}$ (with the presentation you gave above), should be the kind of a infinite non-elementary hyperbolic group in which the maximal order of a torsion-element is exponential in with respect to the hyperbolicity constant.